# Can an Aetherborn Marauder take +1/+1 counters off a creature that didn't have them (but has P/T to spare)?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

So my brother play [Aetherborn Marauder](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAetherborn%20Marauder%5d). He wants to move three +1/+1 counters from a 4/4 with no previous interaction with any +1/+1 counters. I insist that a +1/+1 counter must have been put on it first, and that its base P/T are not applicable due to the use of the word "counter".

Anyone able to quote the rulebook for this one?

Comment: Yes, you can't MOVE counters from a permanent without counters obviously. Finding this in the comp rules might be harder.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the rules :

> 121.5. If an effect says to “move” a counter, it means to take that counter from the object it’s currently on and put it onto a second
>   object. If the first and second objects are the same object, nothing
>   happens. **If the first object has no counters, nothing happens; the
>   second object doesn’t get a counter put on it.** If the second object
>   (or any possible second objects) is no longer in the correct zone when
>   the effect would move the counter, nothing happens; a counter isn’t
>   removed from the first object.

Your Aetherborn Marauder doesn't get any counter if the target of its ETB ability doesn't have counters when the ability resolve.

Comment: I didn't see "target" in the phrasing of its ETB.

Answer (score 1):

A creature's power and toughness aren;t counters in and of themselves, they are characteristics of the 'Creature' card type. From the [Comprehensive rules](http://media.wizards.com/2017/downloads/MagicCompRules_20170428.txt), ad 302:

> 302.4. Power and toughness are characteristics only creatures have.
>
> 302.4a A creature’s power is the amount of damage it deals in combat.
>
> 302.4b A creature’s toughness is the amount of damage needed to destroy it.
>
> 302.4c To determine a creature’s power and toughness, start with the numbers printed in its lower right corner, [...]

These can then be altered using enchantments, instants, sorceries, abilities of sources such as other creatures or planeswalkers, and artifacts/equipment. Most of these effects are temporary in that they only last until end of turn ([Giant Growth](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGiant%20Growth%5d), or while the source is in play ([Glorious Anthem](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGlorious%20Anthem%5d)). And sometimes this boost is done using counters which stay with the permanent when its source leaves play ([Bond Beetle](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBond%20Beetle%5d)).

Counters are governed by their own set of rules:

> 121. Counters
>
> 121.1. A counter is a marker placed on an object or player that modifies its characteristics and/or interacts with a rule, ability, or effect. Counters are not objects and have no characteristics.[...]

And onwards...

In conclusion, you can only move a counter from a permanent when that counter is there in the first place, and base P/T are not counters.